# How to create appcontroller in zend

Tags: zend-framework

In email functionality there will possible that many time email will send for some action in application.So is there any way to create appcontroller in zend so that we can use it format in whole application.

Please help if any one know about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a controller for that at all. Just create a class, say Application_Email, and use it from anywhere.

Comment: may I know where put Application_Email in application.

Comment: Wherever you like. I find it convenient to put all the classes to the library directory. So I'd put this file to library/Application/Email.php

Comment: Thanks akond,
Can you tell me if I want to appcontroller and extend that controller into all my controller like usercontroller,productcontroller.
Please let me know if is there any way to do?